# How to mark a question as solved?

Tags: support, questions, answers

Recently I asked a question about Android. It was answered the next day. Now I would like to mark the question as answered or solved.

Is there a standard way to do it? If yes, where to find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On SE sites, you don't mark the *question* as solved – but you mark the answer as solution, so it stands out and can easily be identified by other people with a similar problem. The exact details are described in our help center: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](//android.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) with a link to [accept the answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and **[How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).**